# What is the inverse function of $F(x)=1+\log_{1/3}(1-x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**What is the inverse function of  $F(x)=1+\log_{1/3}(1-x)$** .. **the base is $1/3$**

I interchanged $x$ with $y$ then I didn't know what next should I do..

Comment: Use the fact that $$\log_{1/3} x = y \iff \left(\frac 1 3\right)^y = x$$

Comment: Or, if you don't like fractional bases for logarithms, you can write $ \ \log_{1/3} \ (1-x) \ = \ -\log_3 \ (1-x) \ $ .

Answer (score 1):

put $F(x) = y$

therefrore

$y = 1$ + $log_{1/3}{(1-x)}$

$x = 1$ +$log_{1/3}{(1-y)}$

$log_{1/3}{(1-y)}$ = $x-1$

Taking antilog both sides

$1-y$ = $(1/{3)^{x-1}}$

$y$ = $1$-${{(1/3)}^{x-1}}$

This is the inverse function of the given function

Answer (score 1):

Let be $f:(-\infty,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=1+\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(1-x)$. Then, $1-x>0$ and so $x<1$. This shows that $D(f)= (-\infty,1)$.

The function $f$ is injective because $\forall a,b \in (-\infty,1)$ we have that
$$f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow 1+\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(1-a)= 1+\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(1-b)\Rightarrow $$
$$\Rightarrow \log_{\frac{1}{3}}(1-a)=\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(1-b)\Rightarrow 1-a=1-b \Rightarrow a=b.$$

The function $f$ is surjective because $\forall z\in \mathbb{R}$, exists a $x\in (-\infty, 1)$ such that $f(x)=z$. Indeed, just take $x=1-(\frac{1}{3})^{z-1}$:
$$f(x)=f(1-(\frac{1}{3})^{z-1})=1+\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(1-(1-(\frac{1}{3})^{z-1}))=1+\log_{\frac{1}{3}}((\frac{1}{3})^{z-1})=1+(z-1)=z. $$

Then, $f$ is bijective and then exists inverse $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (-\infty,1)$ given by:
$$x=f^{-1}(y) =1-(\frac{1}{3})^{y-1}.$$

---

Note: To find the expression $x=1−(\frac{1}{3})^{z−1}$ we need to isolate the variable $x$ in the expression $z=f(x)=1+\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(1-x)$ as follows:

$$z=1+\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(1-x)\Rightarrow z-1=\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(1-x)\Rightarrow  $$
$$\Rightarrow 1-x=(\frac{1}{3})^{z-1}\Rightarrow x= 1-(\frac{1}{3})^{z-1}.$$